# Error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'" Attempting to plot a NACA Airfoil

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to plot the NACA 0012 Airfoil in python using the NACA thickness distribution equation but can't seem to get past this error. My code for the block:

I tried to use a loop to conduct this operation.

```
t = 0.12 #thickness
c = 1.0 #chord
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 101) #100 distribution points for x from 0 to 1
z = np.zeros(len(x))
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[i] = (t*c/0.2)*[0.296*((x[i]/c)**(1/2)) - 0.1260*(x[i]/c) - 0.3516*((x[i]/c)**2) + 0.2843*((x[i]/c)**3) - 0.1015*((x[i]/c)**4)]
```

Comment: don't use square brackets in your equation - you can only use regular (round?) brackets there

Comment: i.e. ```z[i] = (t*c/0.2)*(0.296*((x[i]/c)**(1/2)) - 0.1260*(x[i]/c) - 0.3516*((x[i]/c)**2) + 0.2843*((x[i]/c)**3) - 0.1015*((x[i]/c)**4))```

Comment: `[1,2,3]*3` is list replication.  `[1,2,3]*1.2` produces this error.